# Create d3 polygon from Image (Binary Mask)

Tags: d3.js

I have the following image. Does anyone have any ideas regarding how to turn the white area into a polygon for use in d3.js? I need a dynamic solution that can be used for thousands of these of varying shapes

[image]

Comment: with `inkscape` trace the path and look in the saved svg for the path definition. or just use `paint` to find the `x,y` coords and construct the path yourself. it looks like there are no curves in there, or do you want curves then `inkscape` is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks rio but not really what I'm looking for. I have added more detail to my question

Comment: With openCV you can find contours in binary images and based on these coordinates you can construct an SVG path.

Comment: Did you find a solution?